# debugger in code lite opens and closes immediately

Tags: debugging, codelite

i am a student and i use the debugger to know what is really going on on the background using break points  when i start the debugger  it opens and closes at the moment , note : using c++

i have tried to delete all break points and add them back but nothing changed

```cpp
int main()
{
    Base b; // i added break point here 

    Derived d {100}; // and here 


    return 0;
}
```

the debugger windows (as watch) opens and closes immediately 
this is the build output :

> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C ""C:/Users/Hussein Okasha/Downloads/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -j8 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile"
>   "----------Building project:[ ConstructorsAndDestructors - Debug ]----------"
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/c++ projects/test/ConstructorsAndDestructors'
>   "C:/Users/Hussein Okasha/Downloads/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"  -c  "D:/c++ projects/test/ConstructorsAndDestructors/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
>   "C:/Users/Hussein Okasha/Downloads/mingw64/bin/g++.exe" -o ./Debug/ConstructorsAndDestructors @"ConstructorsAndDestructors.txt" -L.
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/c++ projects/test/ConstructorsAndDestructors'
>   ====0 errors, 0 warnings====
>   and this is the output :
>   Current working directory: D:\c++ projects\test\ConstructorsAndDestructors\Debug
>   Running program: le_exec.exe D:/c++ projects/test/1/1.project
>   Program exited with return code: -1073741510

Answer (score 0):

The solution is so simple you just go to **build**->**clean project**